# Copy method of worksheet class failed with Pivot table created in Power Pivot

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot

I have a pivot table created in Power Pivot, it's on a sheet ("Sups") that when using VBA to copy and paste will work sometimes and in other instances, it will not, triggering the "Copy method of worksheet class failed" error.

The line that triggers the error is the **dailyWb.Sheets("Sups").Copy Before:=newWb.Sheets("Reps Bonus")**

Any wisdom?

```
Sub sendEmail()

Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set OutMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim toList As String, ccList As String, filepath As String


Dim dailyWb As Workbook
Dim openWb As Workbook
Set dailyWb = ThisWorkbook
Dim range_data As Range, range_data2 As Range, range_data3 As Range, range_data4 As Range, range_data5 As Range
Dim path As String, stats As String
Dim year As String
Dim today As Date, yesterday As Date

    year = dailyWb.Sheets("Values").Range("K5").Value
    today = dailyWb.Sheets("Values").Range("K1").Value
    yesterday = dailyWb.Sheets("Values").Range("K2").Value
    filepath = dailyWb.Sheets("Values").Range("K6").Value
    toList = dailyWb.Sheets("Values").Range("K13").Value
    ccList = dailyWb.Sheets("Values").Range("K14").Value
    stats = dailyWb.Sheets("Values").Range("C22").Value   
    Call refresher
Set newWb = Workbooks.Add

'Copying a worksheet from ThisWorkbook into newly created workbook in the above statement

    dailyWb.Worksheets("Reps").Visible = True
    dailyWb.Sheets("Reps").Copy Before:=newWb.Sheets(1)
    newWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
    newWb.Sheets(1).Columns("A:K").Delete
    newWb.Sheets(1).Range("C3").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    dailyWb.Worksheets("Booked Orders").Visible = True
    dailyWb.Sheets("Booked Orders").Copy After:=newWb.Sheets("Reps")
    dailyWb.Worksheets("New Orders").Visible = True
    dailyWb.Sheets("New Orders").Copy After:=newWb.Sheets("Booked Orders")
    newWb.Sheets("New Orders").Columns("O").Delete
    dailyWb.Worksheets("Shipped Sales").Visible = True
    dailyWb.Sheets("Shipped Sales").Copy Before:=newWb.Sheets("New Orders")
    dailyWb.Worksheets("Rep Bonus").Visible = True
    dailyWb.Sheets("Rep Bonus").Copy After:=newWb.Sheets("New Orders")
    dailyWb.Worksheets("Dispositions MTD").Visible = True
    dailyWb.Sheets("Dispositions MTD").Copy Before:=newWb.Sheets("Rep Bonus")
    dailyWb.Worksheets("Interaction").Visible = True
    dailyWb.Sheets("Interaction").Copy Before:=newWb.Sheets("Reps Bonus")
    dailyWb.Worksheets("Sups").Visible = True
    dailyWb.Sheets("Sups").Copy Before:=newWb.Sheets("Reps Bonus")
    newWb.Sheets("Reps").Activate

End Sub
```